# What is the point of being able to attach / link shaders multiple times?

Tags: performance, opengl, shader

there is something I don't fully understand with OpenGL:  According to everything I'm reading, you get the best performance by compiling the shaders just long enough to attach them to a program, and then it is recommended you delete the shader itself to free memory and just track the program until it's deleted.

So my question is this:  if the above is true, what's the purpose of being able to attach shaders and re-link the program after it's been created?  Isn't it more efficient to just create a second shader program and swap between them during scene creation instead of detaching/attaching and re-linking programs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you get the best performance by compiling the shaders just long enough to attach them to a program, and then it is recommended you delete the shader itself to free memory and just track the program until it's deleted

This activity would have no bearing on *rendering performance*; it may help reduce memory usage by the driver, but it won't help you get triangles on the screen faster.  The process of compiling shaders is modeled after compiling programs, and your comment would be identical to deleting object files after you've compiled the full executable.

> What's the purpose of being able to attach shaders and re-link the program after it's been created?

This lets you skip recompiling all of the shaders required for a program, and only relink the compiled shaders (which are different than linked shader programs) to make a new program.  Again using the parallel with building an executable, it's like using a different set of object files to make a new executable.  You don't need to recompile everything from source, just feed the appropriate files into the linker.

> Isn't it more efficient to just create a second shader program and swap between them during scene creation instead of detaching/attaching and re-linking programs?

Certainly that's the thinking of many in the industry.  While the performance is dependent on the OpenGL driver implementation you're using, common sense would suggest that it's faster to just "load" the new shader into the pipeline than updating the state to configure the shader program linking, perform the link, and then "load" the new shader.